# Finiteness property of virtually torsion-free groups

Tags: group-theory

> Do virtually torsion-free groups always have finitely many conjugacy classes of finite subgroups?

A paper I'm reading about $\operatorname{Out}(F_n)$ mentions this finiteness property is a corollary of it being virtually torsion-free, but I'm having difficulty seeing how to establish this fact. Is it possible that a proof uses more structure of $\operatorname{Out}(F_n)$ than it being virtually torsion-free?

Really any hints would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to find examples of groups that are not finitely generated  in which this is not true, but it appears that it not true in general, even for finitely generated groups. There is an example [here](http://berstein.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/groups-having-finitely-many-conjugacy-classes-of-finite-order-elements/):

let $G = (F_2 \times F_2) \rtimes C_2 =$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \langle a,b,c,d,t \mid t^2=1, a^t=b,  c^t=d, 
[a,c]=[b,c]=[a,d]=[b,d]=1 \rangle,$

let $\phi:G \to {\mathbb Z}$ with $a,b,c,d \mapsto 1$, $t \mapsto 0$, and let $H= \ker \phi$. Then $H$ is virtually torsion-free and has infinitely many classes of finite order elements. The group $H$ is not finitely presented, so it would be interesting to know if there is a finitely presented example.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something. Why is $H$ virtually free?

Comment: Wait did you mean virtually torsion free? That I think should be easy to show.

Comment: $H$ is definitely not virtually free, but it is virtually torsion-free since $G$ clearly is.

Comment: Sorry, yes I meant virtually torsion free.

Comment: Is $G$ of type $F_3$? Then the 1-2-3 Theorem would do the trick (as then the fibre product is finitely presented and contains $H$ as a normal subgroup).

Comment: But the $H$ in this example is definitely not finitely presentable.

Comment: @DerekHolt That is the point of the 1-2-3 Theorem. If you have a short exact sequence $$1\rightarrow N\rightarrow G\mathop{\rightarrow}^p Q\rightarrow 1$$ with $N$ finitely generated (type $F_1$), $Q$ finitely presented (type $F_2$) and $G$ of type $F_3$ then the following subgroup of $G\times G$ is finitely presentable. $$\{(g, h): p(g)=p(h), g, h\in G\}$$ It seems that this subgroup has the required properties. However, when I think about it now I doubt that the group $G$ here is of type $F_3$, because the group $F_2\times F_2$ is not of type $F_3$ (these $F_n$s have different meanings).